# Double pointer dereferences in a function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand double pointers. I think i should be able to write (**min = 3;) in the MinMax loop below, but it is just ignored. I think it should set the value pointed to by the value of min (pointer to start) to 3 (or of course to any int). Can someone help me understand why this is crazy talk? There is no reason in the function to set this value of course, i just want to understand why it doesn't work.

```
int ar[] = {1,23,4,32,5,67,999,-1};
int *min= 0;
int *max= 0;
MinMax(ar,ar+8,&min,&max);

void MinMax(int *start,int *end, int **min,int **max) {
  // **min = 3; //why not?
  *min = start; 
  *max = start;
  while(++start < end) {
  if(*start < **min) *min = start;
  if(*start > **max) *max = start;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is almost always confusing to use the same name for objects used at different places, especially when they have different levels of indirection. In the context of the calling code, `min` is a pointer to an integer. In the function `MinMax()`, it is the address of a pointer to an integer. Any discussion about `min` is going to be ambiguous.

Comment: regarding: `MinMax(ar,ar+8,&min,&max);`  this seems to be a prototype for the actual function.  If that is correct, then it is written wrong.  Prototypes should use the parameter types like `int`, `char`, etc.  The names of actual data is totally optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point you have `**min = 3` the value of `*min` is 0, i.e. a NULL pointer, which means it doesn't point anywhere.  Attempting to dereference `*min` and subsequently write to it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The following lines set both `*min` and `*max` to point to the same place as `start`, so after that they can be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

On entering the function *min is zero so **min = 3 is setting an integer at address zero to three. Not normally allowed at run time. It is only after initialising *min to a valid address, for example *min = start, that you can then set **min to a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MinMax(int *start,int *end, int **min,int **max) {
    // **min = 3;
```

You start with initializing your function's argument to point to null so `**min` is not a defined value (`*min` is null but dereferencing a null pointer is UB.) To make `**min` a valid object, first set `*min` to point to a valid object, for instance

```
int *min = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

(don't forget to deallocate it later) or

```
int m = 0;
int *min = &m;
```

or even

```
int *min = ar;
```

(thought that latter is already performed in `MinMax`.)

Comment: I don't think this is helpful to solving the misunderstanding. *min is overridden so the allocation will be orphaned.

Comment: Sure it will if the function is kept in its current form. The thing is, once line commented out is uncommented, more changes are required.